# Notification style error when bigtext

Tags: android, android-notifications

i am showing notification from following code but problem is when text is small it not showing but when text is big then it showing

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon).setContentTitle(title).setAutoCancel(true).setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(mBuilder).bigText(body));
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

    mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mBuilder.setSound(soundUri); // notification sound

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationId = Integer.valueOf(last4Str);

    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Visit this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html

Comment: i think i am doing same but still